# Can't find one of the errors in my Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure what I did to it, I had it working a while ago, but i cannot seem to find what I'm forgetting. I've been trying to find it for a while now, any help is appreciated.

I was working on the ageDate and ageTime sections when it stopped working, if that helps at all

```
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  Welcome to the Age Calculator!
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>


  <form name="form">
    Birth Year:
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="birthYear">
    <br>Current Year:
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="currentYear">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>Birth Month:
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="birthMonth">
    <br>Current Month
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="currentMonth">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>Birth Date
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="birthDate">
    <br>Current Date
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="currentDate">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>Birth Time (Convert time to a decimial Ex: 9:45pm = 21.75
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="birthTime">
    <br>Current Time
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="currentTime">
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id="Submit_Button" onclick="test();" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Submit">Submit</a>
  </form>




  <script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {

      var currentYear = document.getElementById("currentYear");
      var birthYear = document.getElementById("birthYear");
      var ageYear = (currentYear.value - birthYear.value)


      var birthMonth = document.getElementById("birthMonth");
      var currentMonth = document.getElementById("currentMonth");
      if (birthMonth.value < currentMonth.value) {
        var ageMonth = (currentMonth.value - birthMonth.value)
      } else {
        var ageMonth = (12 - (birthMonth.value - currentMonth.value))
      }



      var birthDate = document.getElementById("birthDate");
      var currentDate = document.getElementById("currentDate");
      if (birthDate.value < currentDate.value) {
        var ageDate = (currentDate.value - birthDate.value);
      } else {
        var ageDat = (30 - birthDate.value);
        var ageDate = (curentDate.value + ageDat);
      }

      var birthTime = document.getElementById("birthTime");
      var currentTime = document.getElementById("currentTime");
      if (birthTime.value > currentTime.value) {
        var ageTim = ((birthTime.value + currentTime.value) % 1);
        var ageTime = ((24 - (birthTime.value - ageTim) + currentTime.value);
        } else {
          var ageTim = ((currentTime.value - birthTime.value) % 1);
          var ageTime = ((currentTime.value - birthTime.value) - ageTim);

        }

        alert("You are " + ageYear + " years, " + ageMonth + " months, " + ageDate + " days, " + ageTime + " hours, and " + ageMin + " minutes old.");
      }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: And what line of code is causing the error?

Comment: You could just open the javascript console and see the error.

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error. This:

```
var ageTime = ((24 - (birthTime.value - ageTim) + currentTime.value);
```

should be:

```
var ageTime = (24 - (birthTime.value - ageTim) + currentTime.value);
```